# how to use directive @push in blade template laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, dom, include, laravel-blade

I need script only on one page. and it should load after jQuery. 
I tried in index.blade

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset ('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
@push('custom-scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset ('js/custom-scripts.js') }}"></script>
@endpush
```

and then I should use @stack('custom-scripts') in my view?

Comment: Yes, this how push and stack is used. Is it not working?

Comment: @DavidHallbergJönsson , is not working. in index.blade  (main view) I include all js. like 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset ('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset ('js/plugins.js') }}"></script>

@push('custom-scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset ('js/custom-scripts.js') }}"></script>
@endpush
` 
and then in a child view I wrote 
`@stack('custom-scripts')`

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You just need to make that the opposite way, `@push` is meant to be in the **child** view, which is pushing content to the parent `@stack` directive.

So your index.blade.php should have a:

```
@stack('custom-scripts')
```

And your child view:

```
@push('custom-scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset ('js/custom-scripts.js') }}"></script>
@endpush
```

You can also use `@parent` directive with `@section` like this:

```
//index.blade.php
@yield('scripts')


//child.blade.php
@section('scripts')
    @parent
    <!-- The rest of your scripts -->
@endsection
```

If you need more info I'd recommend you to check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#stacks).  Hope this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Using `@once` might be also helpful for someone to prevent scripts from being executed more than once. You can define your root view to have a fixed place for scripts that should go at the end of the `<head>` tag and at the end of the `<body>` tag:

`app.blade.php`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Website</title>
    @stack('head-scripts')
  </head>

  <body>
    <main>@yield('content')</main>

  @stack('body-scripts')
  </body>
</html>
```

`home.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div>Hello World</div>

    @push('body-scripts')
        @once
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/imask"></script>
        @endonce
    @endpush
@endsection
```

Comment: yup but @once you need if you are pushing script inside loop / recursion or for some reason you are pushing that specific section multiple time then once will make sure to add that script only once. else you do not need that.